# Hot to custom parse with GSON?

Tags: java, gson

My JSON object is like this:

```
{

    "id": 911,
    "slug": "andreas-nikotini",
    "title": "Nikotini (Greek-Russian Dance Pop)",
    "picture": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ellostatic/video_thumb/911/53e29f833eb372c72d127a298723edf9.jpeg",
    "artists": 

[

        {
            "name": "Andreas"
        }
    ],
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "like_count": 177,
    "view_count": 29752,
    "is_favorite": false

}
```

And I parse it to next object:

```
public class RelatedVideoGSON {

    int                   id;
    String                slug;
    String                title;
    String                picture;
    String                favorite_count;
    ArrayList<ArtistGSON> artists;
    String                like_count;
    String                view_count;
    boolean               is_favorite;
}
```

Where like_count, view_count, and favorite_count are Integers.
I want to add thousand separator to the Integers, while object is parsing. How can I do that?

Comment: If `like_count` etc. are integers, why do you have them declared as strings? And what do you mean that you want to add "coma separator" (sic)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I get them as 29752 (view_count from example) and what them to be a string like 29,752. They are only to be displayed in textviews

Comment: Oh you want thousand separation. That is a *presentation* issue only, don't store the values like that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it's just not very good example. My main concern is how to change output  of Gson parsing. I interested in that, because I load object from net in separate thread (as it have to be in android), but if i then want to make alteration for big bunch of object, I have to start another thread (to not overload UIThread) and that is also very costly and messy.

Comment: And if you want to change the value? Then you have to parse the string in the structure and convert it to an integer, change it, and convert it back to a string? How is that different better than only convert to a formatted string *when needed*? Also, don't *force* a specific number format on the users, the user will have a locale set and if you use the correct controls the numbers should be formatted according to the users preferences automatically. *Possible* thousands separation, as well as things like decimal point or comma is a pure *presentation* issue.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg may be I have error in my logic, but I thought: if a json object is basically a String, there will not be a nessesity to convert Substring to Integer, but straight String modification. And lets consider that earlier I mentioned not a thousand separator, but representing thouthands as 2k and millions, as 3m. (Yes I am aware that String take much more space  than int)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of doing this is: (if it's me, I won't bother digging into the Gson parsing mechanism :-) )

- parse the string/json to a general `HashMap<Object, Object>` map
- modify the specific key-values as you like.
- dump the modified map to string/json again.
- re-parse the dumped string/json to the final object you want.

This procedure may seems not  elegant, but the problem itself is not elegant anyway, comma splited string which represents numbers like 4,532,345 should only be done at the very front-end rather than stored in structure.

---

PS: You can parse a general HashMap from string by code like this:

```
HashMap<Object, Object> m = gson.fromJson(s, new TypeToken<Map<Object, Object>>(){}.getType());
```